# How to use Apex Schedule Job UI in custom lightning component without customization

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, scheduled-apex, scheduled-job

We would like to create a lightning component to display the Apex Schedule Job UI(Customized), could anyone please let me know if there is any option to display Apex Schedule Job UI without customizing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any direct/standard solutions.
https://crmcog-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/packagingSetupUI/ipLanding.app?apvId=04tE0000000ISIu - was being discussed sometime ago. I am not sure whether it is actively maintained (you can try that!).

Welkin suite could do scheduling as well, but it is too expensive to buy for just scheduling jobs!